# Extend HTML element to browser-height?

Tags: html, css, scrolltop, scrollto

I'm building a Single-Page layout with a navigation for scrolling to several anchors (anchor locks on top of the page - height of the header). The scrolling content is only structured in headlines `<h3>` and paragraphs `<p>`. Works well so far, but the last section of the page is quite short, so it gets stuck on the page's bottom and has not enough "space/content" to even arrive at the top of the page.

Does anyone know a way to extend the very last `<p>` to the browser's height (- the header's height), so that it can reach the top?

CSS-only would be great, jQuery is fine aswell.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show demo fiddle

Comment: Not just a fiddle please, but some minmal code in your quiestion so we can replicate the problem.

Comment: You could use some jQuery to apply the HTML page height to the height of the last `<p>` on the page. This is getting a bit messy though...

Comment: I really should write a bot that upvotes each and every comment that says "use some jQuery".

Comment: Or maybe I should write a bot always responding with [this link](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description you seem to have something like this, where I'm giving your "scrolling content" area an id of `application-body` like this:

```
<div id="application-body">
    <h3 id="n-1">Headline 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-2">Headline 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-3">Headline 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-4">Headline 4</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-5">Headline 5</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-6">Headline 6</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-7">Headline 7</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-8">Headline 8</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-9">Headline 9</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-10">Headline 10</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <h3 id="n-11">Headline 11</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
</div><!--#application-body-->
```

And you want to make the last element in that list - the last `<p>` element in this case, artificially taller so it will work correctly. If I'm not mistaken I think what you want is this:

```
#application-body p:last-child {
    color: red;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Which will increase the height arbitrarily as you see fit. Not sure what the constraints of your page are, but you could also experiment with other units. I don't think percentage height will do what you intend though. `em` might work as well. You might also consider setting the height with a media query so that if the height was not very tall you could set it lower.

Here's more about [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)

---

If you simply must use jQuery or must get precise about the height you want, you'd want to use this chunk of jQuery. Note that your header must have an id of header for this code to work. Adjust to your own site.

```
var targetHeight = $(window).height() - $('#header').height();
$('#application-body p:last-child').height(targetHeight);
```

Comment: artlung's jQuery snippet does the job! Sorry for the missing code/fiddle and thanks for the answers.